# How to move multiple columns of values between list boxes using VBA in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, search, filter, ms-access-2016

I am setting up the backend for a search/filtering interface in MS Access.

The interface for reference.
[image: front end]

The 'search filter', 'search box', 'select filter' and 'select component' controls work.
I am struggling with the 'Component List'.

I would like to move rows between the 'Select Component' and the 'Component List' using the four buttons: Add, Add All, Remove & Remove All.
It only adds the first column value to the 'Component List' list box and then displays

> Runtime error 424: Object required

and highlights the following line of code:

```
Me.SearchFilter_List4.Column(0, Me.SearchFilter_List4.ListCount - 1) = Me.SearchFilter_List3.Column(0, selectedRow)
```

Clicking the add button is supposed to add three column headings (the same as the 'Select Component' list box), and then move the entire row across.

The code for the 'Add Button' and the 'ListBoxItemExists' function:

For reference:
'Select Component' = 'SearchFilter_List3'
'Component List' = 'SearchFilter_List4'

```vb
Private Sub Add_Button_Click()
    Dim selectedRow As Integer
    selectedRow = Me.SearchFilter_List3.ListIndex
    
    ' Check if a row is selected
    If selectedRow <> -1 Then
        Dim selectedValue As String
        selectedValue = Me.SearchFilter_List3.Column(0, selectedRow)
        
        ' Check if the selected component is already present in SearchFilter_List4
        If ListBoxItemExists(Me.SearchFilter_List4, selectedValue) Then
            MsgBox "Duplication Error: Part already added to component list."
        Else
            ' Check if the table headings are already present in SearchFilter_List4
            If Me.SearchFilter_List4.ColumnCount = 0 Then
                ' Add table headings to SearchFilter_List4
                Me.SearchFilter_List4.ColumnCount = 3
                Me.SearchFilter_List4.ColumnWidths = "1000;1000;1000"
                Me.SearchFilter_List4.AddItem "Part Description"
                Me.SearchFilter_List4.AddItem "EBOM"
                Me.SearchFilter_List4.AddItem "AAR Number"
            End If
            
            ' Add the selected row to SearchFilter_List4 and hide it in SearchFilter_List3
            Me.SearchFilter_List4.AddItem ""
            Me.SearchFilter_List4.Column(0, Me.SearchFilter_List4.ListCount - 1) =       Me.SearchFilter_List3.Column(0, selectedRow) ' Part_Description
            Me.SearchFilter_List4.Column(1, Me.SearchFilter_List4.ListCount - 1) = Me.SearchFilter_List3.Column(1, selectedRow) ' EBOM
            Me.SearchFilter_List4.Column(2, Me.SearchFilter_List4.ListCount - 1) = Me.SearchFilter_List3.Column(2, selectedRow) ' AAR_Number
            Me.SearchFilter_List3.RemoveItem selectedRow
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Function ListBoxItemExists(lstBox As ListBox, value As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Check if the specified value exists in the given ListBox
    For i = 0 To lstBox.ListCount - 1
        If lstBox.Column(0, i) = value Then
            ListBoxItemExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    ListBoxItemExists = False
End Function
```

I tried the `.List` and `.Selected` properties, and used a number of different methods. They all to break at this same line of code.

Comment: AFAIK, listbox RowSource list is set with SQL or VBA to build a ValueList string. Where did you find example of setting Columns? Review: https://office-watch.com/2010/adding-and-deleting-listbox-items-part-1/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LlzVrx6OkU

Comment: Not a minimal reproducible example; too much work.  I suggest you put labels above your listboxes instead of using column headings.  I suggest using an item-locations 1to1 table instead of value lists.  Here is another example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LlzVrx6OkU